# print PDF file without opening the acrobat reader

Tags: vb.net, pdf, visual-studio-2013

Click a button then print PDF file without opening the acrobat reader. How to do that in VB.net 2013?

The code below works, but it opens acrobat reader first then print.

```
Dim proc As Process = Process.Start("AcroRd32.exe", _
                              String.Format("/N /T {0} ""{1}""", _
                              "C:\Path\to\201402124_label.pdf", "Brother QL-700")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `/h` switch to open `AcroRd32.exe <filename>` as a minimized window. You can find more info in the [Adobe Developer FAQ doc](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/intro_to_sdk/DeveloperFAQ.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: (c#)

```
    public static Boolean PrintPDFs(string pdfFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.StartInfo.Verb = "print";

            //Define location of adobe reader/command line
            //switches to launch adobe in "print" mode
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/p /h {0}", pdfFileName);
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

            proc.Start();
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            if (proc.HasExited == false)
            {
                proc.WaitForExit(10000);
            }

            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            proc.Close();
            KillAdobe("AcroRd32");
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```